# Symfony forms : Field with condition

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have 2 entities :

- Server
- Application

and I have 2 entites :

- Evenement
- CatEvenement (in her table : a line for Server, a line for Application)

When I create an `Evenement`, I'd like to choose a category (CatEvenement),
and then (ex:) if I select Application's category, I have a field with all of my Application's entity..

How am I supposed to do that pls ?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: What did you try ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: Try Symfony Doc [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). Now its v6.3

Answer (score 0):

In you form add fields like this:

```
$builder
->add('application', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Application',
    'choice_label' => 'Application',
));
->add('server', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Server',
    'choice_label' => 'server',
));
```